# How to start or wakeup azure webjob from sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: azure, workflow

I have an Azure Web-job deployed in Azure and set to run On-demand. I want to Run the Web-Job from Designer workflow when Some field value matches.

So, is there any approach on how to trigger the job from SharePoint designer workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the capabilities of the SharePoint side, but assuming it can make an HTTP POST request, you could trigger the WebJob via the WebJob API:
http://chriskirby.net/blog/running-your-azure-webjobs-with-the-kudu-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If I use the REST API from designer workflow , then How do the azure authentication will be done?
Please let me know if any one faced the same or have any idea.

Comment: Take a look at the "Get Your Creds" section of the link I provided. It shows how to get the username and password that you can use. I am unsure what the configuration/options are on the SharePoint side. You may have to create the header, as shown in the "Run your webjob" section, yourself instead of doing it in code each time. The REST API call will require the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating httpost request along with passing the clientID and clientSecret.

[Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2013/01/23/walk-through-for-building-a-net-application-for-accessing-windows-azure-active-directory-graph-service/)

with respect to above link for creating http post request for webjob.